# Serialize arbitrary complex Java object (with no source code) and load it in Python

Tags: java, python, serialization

I need to serialize a big/complex Java object generated by a library for which I don't have source code.
The reason I need to serialize it is to being able to then load it in Python.

So, I don't need to be able to de-serialize the generated file back to the orginal Java object. I just need to generate some reasonably-easy-to-parse file (e.g., json) so that I can then parse it in Python and extract the information I need.

I tried to use the Gson library but I get a recursion error. I suspect the object I am serializing has some circularity.

What I am trying to avoid is to write any custom serialization code in Java, and keep all the "parse and manually de-serialize" code in Python.

I currently have a solution based on Protobuf, but I don't like it, since it requires:

1. custom serialization Java code
2. Protobuf specification
3. custom information extraction in Python.

So, right now, I need to keep "in sinc" 3 pieces of code.

What I would like is a solution like this:

Java object --> "raw" serialized file --> load in Python --> extract info in Python

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think this is too broad; as it is really unclear what exactly you want to achieve. What kind of information are you looking for to find in objects you don't know anything about?

Comment: Does ordinary serialization even work, given the circular references in your Objects?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch normal serialization can handle it.  But frankly, if your object has circular references, you are straight up out of luck; accept your custom solution.